# How to use item.key in other component instead of alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

FlatList Component working complete if i click Android it show in Android in aler but i have to pass that bind value into Subscribe component instead of alert. 
should i have to pass data into state and for use it as a props in other component ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View,Alert } from 'react-native';  

export default class FlatList extends Component {  

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.updateKey = this.updateKey.bind(this);
        this.state = {};
    }

    updateKey(keyData) {
        this.setState({ keyData: keyData });
    }

    getListViewItem = (item) => {  
        Alert.alert(item.key);  
    }  

    render() {  
        return (  
            <View style={styles.container}>  
                <FlatList  
                    data={[  
                        {key: 'Android'},{key: 'iOS'}, {key: 'Java'},{key: 'Swift'},  
                        {key: 'Php'},{key: 'Hadoop'},{key: 'Sap'},  
                    ]}  
                    renderItem={({item}) =>  
                        <Text style={styles.item}  
                              onPress={this.getListViewItem.bind(this, item)}>{item.key}</Text>}          
                />  
            </View>  
        );  
    }  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {  
        flex: 1,  
    },  
    item: {  
        padding: 10,  
        fontSize: 18,  
        height: 44,  
    },  
})  
AppRegistry.registerComponent('flatList', () => FlatList);
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Item } from 'react-native';

export default class Subscribe extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View>
               <Text>{item.key}</Text>
           </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to use that value in another component you'll have to pass it as a prop

Comment: How can i use can you send me code ?

Comment: Reformatted code. Some of it was being cut off by using the ``` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to pass it as prop to a child component you can set it inside your state and pass it to the child component you are talking about.

To accomplish this you just have to change your `Alert` to: `this.setState( { selectedValue: item } )`

Then your child would look something like:

```
<Child item = {this.state.selectedValue} />
```

And you will be able to access it in your child simply doing:

```
this.props.item
```